# How do I exclude inputs from a specific input?

Tags: python

For example, I want to exclude inputs other than "G,T,A and C" from an input. How do I do this?

So, this is what I'm working on right now.:

```
a=input('What is your DNA sequence?: ')
```

I need to exclude inputs other than "G,T,A and C" from this.

Comment: What do you mean by "exclude"? For example, what's your expected output if the input is `GUAC`? Please [edit] the question to clarify. BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour], and [ask].

Comment: Also what you want to output if input is `GGGG`

Comment: @Girish That'd be valid. G is included in "G, T, A, and C". And anyway OP's working on DNA, where "GGG" is valid and codes for glycine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use regular expressions for filtering. The most simple example would be:

```
import re

x = input("What is your DNA sequence?: ")
r = re.compile('^[CAGT]+$')

while not r.match(x):
    print ("DNA sequence '" + x + "' invalid")
    x = input("What is your DNA sequence?:")
```

Here regexp `^[CAGT]+$` means that input should match characters C, A, G, or T, which are repeated (`+`) from the beginning of the string (`^`) to its end (`$`).

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
tokens = {'G', 'T', 'A', 'C'}

while True:
    inp = input('>>')

    if inp == 'quit':
        break

    if not set(inp).issubset(tokens):
        print('invalid tokens')
    else:
        print('valid')
```

Sample test cases:

```
>>ATGCCTGGGTACTAA
valid
>>AGTweddc
invalid tokens
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in a while loop that checks if `a` is not "G,T,A or C" to repeat getting input until getting a correct input.

Answer (score 0):

well the input depends on the user. so you can only use a error handler to warn the user if anything else is inputted

```
available_sequence = ["G", "T", "A", "C"]
a=input('What is your DNA sequence?: ')
if a not in available_sequence:
    print("Invalid Input")
```

Comment: "DNA sequence" means more than one letter. OP's valid input would be something like `ATGCCTGGGTACTAA`.

Comment: i am just saying for a single instance. for multiple instances OP should consider creating a array and using a while loop.